# RT-1004 when copying data from destination to Source workbooks

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2007, vba

I use this code to copy data from a workbook that is an import from a report. However, as the month progresses and the amount of data grows, so does the amount of time to run this sub (in the last week of January it took 3 minutes to process 900 rows of data):

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1602_February()

Dim ANS As Long

ANS = MsgBox("Is the February 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - February 2016") = False Then
    MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "2" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

Application.Run "'Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm'!Unfilter"

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "2" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 31)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I asked in Code Review for a more efficient way to achieve the intended results and came up with this:

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1602_February()

Dim ANS As Long

ANS = MsgBox("Is the February 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - February 2016") = False Then
    MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "2" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

Application.Run "'Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm'!Unfilter"

   With sourceWorksheet.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
        .Apply
    End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

Dim sourceWorkBook As Workbook
Set sourceWorkBook = Workbooks("TEMPIMPORT.xlsx")
Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks("Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm")
Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkBook.Sheets("Extract")
Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
Set destinationWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.Sheets("Swivel")
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = sourceWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim sourceRow As Integer
Dim destinationRow As Integer
destinationRow = destinationWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) + 1


For sourceRow = 2 To lastRow
    If Cells(sourceRow, 2) = "2" Then
        destinationWorksheet.Rows(destinationRow) = sourceWorksheet.Rows(sourceRow) ' This is where the Run-Time error occurs
        destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
    End If
Next sourceRow

Call ExtractSave

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But now there is a

**Run-time error '1004': 
Application-defined or object-defined error**

for this line:

```
destinationWorksheet.Rows(destinationRow) = sourceWorksheet.Rows(sourceRow)
```

I have included two snapshots of the Source Data and the target workbook.[image: This is the Source Workbook]

[image: This is the Target Workbook (Some columns are hidden but are really the same as the source workbook)]

This sub is used to clear all filters prior to the copy/paste.

```
Sub Unfilter()

Dim she As Variant
For Each she In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If she.FilterMode Then she.ShowAllData
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with `destinationWorksheet.Rows(destinationRow) = sourceWorksheet.Rows(sourceRow).Value`?  Is the destinationWorksheet protected?  Are the range(s) filtered or otherwise containing multiple `Areas`?

Comment: what is the error description? Please edit your question with description in addition to the number.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have edited the post with the full error message

Comment: @DavidZemens There is no protection enabled in either workbook. There is a line in the sub that runs an unfilter sub located in the target workbook: `Application.Run "'Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm'!Unfilter"` before trying the copy/paste.

Comment: Please include the code for any dependent functions/subs such as the mentioned `Unfilter` procedure.

Comment: As @DavidZemens suggested, try with `.Value` on the end of each statement. If that fails `destinationWorksheet.Rows(destinationRow).Select` and  `sourceWorksheet.Rows(sourceRow).Select` and see if they work as expected. Put these before the value copy line. or in the Immediate window.

Comment: @DavidZemens I just included the code for Unfilter. I did add the .Value and I did not receive the RT1004 error. However, the data was "pasted" beginning in row 2017. The last row of data is located in row 89. So this new data should begin in row 90.

Comment: Okay then you need to examine and debug the code to see where it's a signing that row number. You're using what looks like a very unreliable method of returning the last row in a given worksheet. I'm on mobile right now but there are several very good answers about better ways of doing this. If you fix that assignment that should resolve your problem.

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/

Comment: @DavidZemens So far Adding .Value after each statement has caused some issues. I am going to try .Select, but unfortunately, it will have to wait until tomorrow. My thought is that using .Value is altering the data format and causing some issues. Will keep you posted on what I see tomorrow.

Comment: *my thought...* what makes you think that? Also we've already honed in on a  well known problem with using `.end(xlUp)` to determine the "last row". Have you addressed that issue? Until/unless you know you're working with the appropriate ranges, all bets are off... you may also have trouble pasting invalid formula references (relative references may contribute to the problem idk without seeing your files) as those may raise a 1004 since they fail to evaluate.

Comment: @DavidZemens There are no formulas in either workbook. This is strictly data. I can tell you that each hour that we use these workbooks, the number of rows increases. The source workbook will always be columns A through AA. The destination workbook wil always be A through AE. But, we are only copying A:AA to A:AA. Both workbooks have the same header. For security reasons, I cannot upload the workbooks. I did forget to mention in this question that this code is being run from an Add-in, so any reference to "ThisWorkbook" will not work.

Comment: Also looks like you have unfiltered the destination, but not the source workbook (using ThisWorkbook object in the Unfilter sub, which is in the XLS file you later assign to `destinationWorkbook`  . You should look into that,  as a filtered range in Source might contribute to the error...

Comment: This code also does not even compile. You have referenced a variable before assignment, in this statement: `With sourceWorksheet.Sort`.  The variable `sourceWorksheet` is not assigned until further below in the code. Please revise and post the actual, compiled code that you're really using.

Comment: You still have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279108/rt-1004-when-copying-data-from-destination-to-source-workbooks?noredirect=1#comment58270834_35279108) problem regarding the incorrect row number. You'll need to address that, otherwise the only thing I can tell you with certainty is that your code is absolutely not doing what you think it is doing, nor what you intend it to do, and so any errors are *probably* related to that incorrect row number.

Comment: Try to add `.Row` in this line: `destinationRow = destinationWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: @Fadi No. This gave me a "RT 438 Object doesn't support this property or method". It seems no matter what I do, I get a RT error that is slightly different each time.

Comment: In short, this code needs to 1. Delete any row where the value of column "B" = 2 (This works) 2. Sort the data (this works) 3. Copy remaining data in columns A:AA from **TEMPIMPORT.xlsx** to columns A:AA **Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm** from the next available row down efficiently.

Comment: @IronMan, it is strange to get error in this line `destinationRow = destinationWorksheet.C...` , if  `destinationWorksheet` is correct worksheet.

Comment: @Fadi I know. That is what is driving me crazy. It is the correct worksheet and that workbook is open when I run this.

Comment: @IronMan, You are use `sourceWorksheet` before Dim and Set it, so move `Dim and Set sourceWorksheet` (2 lines) . before this line `With sourceWorksheet.Sort`.

Comment: @Fadi I did correct that as David Zemens pointed out. I just didn't comment on that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (on temp copy of your workbooks):

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1602_February()

Dim ANS As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim uRng As Range
Dim she As Worksheet

 ANS = MsgBox("Is the February 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
 If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - February 2016") = False Then
     MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
     Exit Sub
 End If

Dim sourceWorkBook As Workbook
 Set sourceWorkBook = Workbooks("TEMPIMPORT.xlsx")
Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
 Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks("Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm")
Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
 Set sourceWorksheet = sourceWorkBook.Sheets("Extract")
Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
 Set destinationWorksheet = destinationWorkbook.Sheets("Swivel")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    sourceWorksheet.Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    sourceWorksheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False



    For LR = sourceWorksheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If sourceWorksheet.Range("B" & LR).Value <> "2" Then
         If uRng Is Nothing Then
          Set uRng = sourceWorksheet.Rows(LR)
         Else
          Set uRng = Union(uRng, sourceWorksheet.Rows(LR))
         End If
        End If
    Next LR

    If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.Delete

    'Application.Run "'Swivel - Master - February 2016.xlsm'!Unfilter"
    For Each she In destinationWorkbook.Worksheets
        If she.FilterMode Then she.ShowAllData
    Next



   With sourceWorksheet.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
        .Apply
    End With

    sourceWorksheet.Cells.WrapText = False

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = sourceWorksheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Dim sourceRow As Integer
    Dim destinationRow As Integer
    destinationRow = destinationWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1


    sourceWorksheet.Range("A2:AA" & lastRow).Copy destinationWorksheet.Range("A" & destinationRow)

    'For sourceRow = 2 To lastRow
    '    If Cells(sourceRow, 2) = "2" Then
    '        destinationWorksheet.Rows(destinationRow) = sourceWorksheet.Rows(sourceRow) ' This is where the Run-Time error occurs
    '        destinationRow = destinationRow + 1
    '    End If
    'Next sourceRow

    Call ExtractSave

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU.......again my friend. Tested the whole process and this worked perfect. I see what you did. I also tried defining the range with `"A2:AA" & lastRow`, but not with `.Copy`.

Comment: I also tested this on the January file (which was taking 3 minutes to process and the reason for this code change to begin with) and it completed in a blink.

Comment: @IronMan, You are Welcome my friend. I'm glad that this code help, but I forgot to change all `Integer` to `Long` because `Long` is faster, see this link: [VBA code optimization - why using long instead of integer?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/vba-code-optimization-why-using-long-instead-of-integer.3606971/) .